# Check commit where a file's history was lost

Tags: git, git-commit, git-checkout, git-reset

I have lost some commits in a file. If I check the history of the project, the commits are there, but they are not in the file's history. I suspect that a team member used `git reset` on the file in a merge conflict, loosing the history in the reset, but I am not sure.

How can I find in which commit a file lost its history?

I've tried several ways without luck. I tried `git log --follow {file}`, this fetches the missing commits, but it doesn't show me the commit where the history was lost.

Comment: Both `git-blame` and `git-annotate` mention `-S` option, which allows you to specify your own list of revisions (used as a refsource instead of `git-rev-list` output).

Comment: If you cannot make it work a better way, check out git's bisect command to zero in on the point of failure. http://webchick.net/node/99

Comment: Using `git biscet` was very helpful. Although git told me that the problem was first spotted in Commit X, and that wasn't the case, the commit with the problem was it's grandfather (2 parent commits way)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably right that the changes were lost in a botched merge, and `git log` by default does not show merge commits unless the file is different than *both* parents of the merge. To include these commits, use `git log --full-history <filename>`.